# How do i make padleft work with the below code. I want to do search with out leading zero

Tags: vb.net

With  the below code I can pull info with zero in the front. I am trying to eliminate entering zero for instance 789136 for 0789136. Please advise

```
Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("DATABASE CONNECTION")
    Dim Table As New DataSet
    Dim ZeroFill As String

    If TxtBoxW1.Text = "" Then
        ZeroFill = TxtBoxW1.Text.Trim
        ZeroFill = ZeroFill.PadLeft(4, "0")

        MsgBox(" Please Enter a valid number", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        TxtBoxW1.Focus()

        connection.Open()

    Else
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From TABLENAME where COLNAME = '" & TxtBoxW1.Text.Trim & "'", connection)

        Command = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        ds1 = New DataSet()
        adapter.Fill(ds1, "TABLENAME")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables("TABLENAME")

    End If

    connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to add zeros or remove zeros?

Answer (score 0):

your code does not make sense in many was. I'm not even sure what do you really need with those leading zeros.

***1) Removing leading zeros***

```
Dim Value As String = "0789136"
Dim ValueWithoutLeadingZeros As String = Value.TrimStart("0"c)
```

***2) Other incinsistencies***

Your ***if*** statement tests for empty string in TxtBoxW1. So there's no reason to read this

```
ZeroFill = TxtBoxW1.Text.Trim
ZeroFill = ZeroFill.PadLeft(4, "0")
```

since it will allways result in

```
ZeroFill = "0000"
```

and you're not using this value anyway.

Your connection.open and connection.close shoudl be all in the ***Else*** section, since you're not using it in ***if*** section. But this might be code cleanup consequence.

You should use parameters instead of direct query. Current version is risky for SQL Injection.

You shoudl use Using for Disposable objects.

***3) Guessed version***

I guess you want to trim leading zeros for validation, but pad your value with zeros for SQL search. In that case, your code should look somehow like this:

```
        If TxtBoxW1.Text.Trim(" "c, "0"c).Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox(" Please Enter a valid number", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            TxtBoxW1.Focus()
        Else
            Dim DS As New DataSet
            Using Conn As New SqlConnection("DATABASE CONNECTION"), DA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From TABLENAME where COLNAME = @Param", Conn)
                DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param", TxtBoxW1.Text.Trim.PadLeft(4, "0")))
                Conn.Open()
                DA.Fill(DS, "TABLENAME")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables("TABLENAME")
            End Using 'This will close the Connection for you
        End If
```

Comment: thanks you all for the responses. I figured it out please see my working code below.

Answer (score 0):

My working code below:

Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click

```
    SqlSelect = ""
    sqlwhere = ""
    expsql = sqlfrom & sqlwhere


    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("database connection")
    '  Dim Command As New SqlCommand("Select * from table name where col1=@col1 = '" & TxtBoxW1.Text & "'", connection)

    Dim Table As New DataSet
    Dim sql As New SqlConnection
    Dim ZeroFill As String
```

Dim ds as DataSet
        connection.Open()

```
    If TxtBoxW1.Text <> "" Then
        ZeroFill = TxtBoxW1.Text.Trim
        ZeroFill = ZeroFill.PadLeft(4, "0")
        sqlwhere = ZeroFill


        ' MsgBox(" Please Enter a valid number", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        TxtBoxW1.Focus()

    End If


    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From table name where col1 = " & sqlwhere & "", connection)

    'adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
    Command = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
    ds = New DataSet()
    Try
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Table Name")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables("Table Name")


    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try


    connection.Close()


End Sub
```